OneDrive doesn't show the icons overlays on folders
I recently installed OneDrive on a fresh Windows 11 installation. I noticed that OneDrive no longer shows the overlay icons on the folders. What I see are the icons in the status next to the folders.

However, on my second Windows 11 desktop (OS was freshly installed in 2020), I see icons on the folders.

Please note both computers have the latest version of OneDrive (24.141.0714.0003). Lastly, as a sanity check, I looked into the registry. Both computers have the same OneDrive registry files. Is this a new feature or bug with OneDrive?


How many applications like OneDrive do you have installed? Have you tried to make the status attribute column visible on the other system?

Just the OneDrive. Yes, I tried checking the Status column on another computer. However, it doesn't show anything in the Status column.

Status doesn’t seem to be a column in the second screenshot. Try to determine if the attribute isn’t being set or just not visible

I tried setting that attribute in another Windows 11 computer. The Status columns are empty.

I took a look at my computer. My OneDrive folder does not have the Icon overlay on any of the files I am synchronizing. I suspect OneDrive has likely discontinued its use. I suspect if you look at the OneDrive on each device the version installed will be different. The current version is: 24.141.0714.0003
